# Show that $2\sin{\phi}\sin{\theta}+\frac{2\sin{\phi}\cos{(2\theta)}}{\sin{\theta}}-2\cot{\theta}\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta}=0$ as simply as possible.

Tags: trigonometry, vector-analysis

Using the fewest possible number of trig identities, how do you show that

$\quad2\sin{\phi}\sin{\theta}+\frac{2\sin{\phi}\cos{(2\theta)}}{\sin{\theta}}-2\cot{\theta}\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta}=0$?

Comment: I'd start with the non-trigonometric simplification of dividing-through by the common factor of $2\sin\phi$. (Assuming $\sin \phi\neq 0$, of course. But, then, if $\sin\phi=0$, the equality is trivial.) This reduces a lot of symbolic clutter, clearing the way for some actual trig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Use $$\cos(2\theta) = \cos^2\theta - \sin^2 \theta$$

Answer (score 1):

You see that the only trigonometric function there that doesn't have a single angle is the middle term. In fact, you have a double-angle. Consider expanding that guy with the double angle identity for cosine and see your result magically vanish.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes it's hard to see what's right in front of you!

Answer (score 1):

$$LHS$$ $=\quad2\sin{\phi}\sin{\theta}+\frac{2\sin{\phi}\cos{(2\theta)}}{\sin{\theta}}-2\cot{\theta}\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta}=\frac{2\sin{\phi}\sin^2{\theta}-2\sin{\phi}\sin^2{\theta}+2\sin{\phi}\cos^2{\theta}-2\sin{\phi}\cos^2{\theta}}{sin{\theta}}=\frac{0}{sin{\theta}}=0=RHS$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It is $$2\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)+\frac{2\sin(\phi)\cos(2\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}=\frac{2\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)^2}{\sin(\theta)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by $\dfrac{\sin\theta}{2\sin\phi}$, and get

$$\sin^2{\theta}+\cos{(2\theta)}-\cos^2{\theta}=0.$$